# Changing Date and Time of Heroku(ruby on rails) Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am having ruby on rails application which is hosted on Heroku. For testing purpose I have to change Date and Time of the server.
Or set it manually to particular date..? 
Is there any way I can do that..?
Using console or anything.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I achieved this with the [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem using an `around_action` to change the time in my staging environment.

```
module TimeTravelFilters
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    if Time::Clock.travel_ok?
      around_action :time_travel_for_request
    end
  end

  def time_travel_for_request
    time_travel
    yield
    time_travel_return
  end

  def time_travel
    if Time::Clock.fake_time
      Timecop.travel Time::Clock.fake_time
    else
      Timecop.return
    end
  end

  def time_travel_return
    Timecop.return
  end
end
```

`Time::Clock` is my own class that keeps track of the fake time.

I have a separate `TimeController` that lets me change the time on the server.

```
class TimeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_admin!

  def index
  end

  def update
    @clock.update_attributes params[:time_clock]
    redirect_to time_index_path
  end

  def destroy
    @clock.reset
    redirect_to time_index_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Kevin worked for me. It changed the time Ruby server not the heroku server.
Whenever I restart Heroku, it changes date to current date. (y)

Comment: That's right. It's useful for testing series of steps that are spread over a period of time.

Comment: @KevinLawrence Ooh this is smart and basically exactly what I would need at the moment (testing a date-dependent workflow on Heroku) - any chance you have this as an Engine or otherwise ready to go somewhere?

Comment: Sorry. I don't Note that Rail now has the time travel methods built in now so you don't need Timecop.

Comment: Ah too bad but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cant change the date time but you can change the timezone

```
heroku config:add TZ="America/Los_Angeles"
```

http://blog.pardner.com/2012/08/setting-the-default-time-zone-for-a-heroku-app/

Comment: as i said you cannot change date time but you can change the timezone by running command manually

Answer (score 1):

For Rails apps running on Heroku, by default Time.now and some_time.localtime will display in UTC. If you'd like to assign a timezone to your app, you can set the TZ config variable to a time zone (which must be in the tz database timezone format).

```
heroku config:add TZ="America/Los_Angeles"
```